# Обработать json массив на стороне клиента (js)

Tags: php, массивы, ajax, json

Есть такой код

```
function update(){
    $.ajax({          
        url: "/controller/update.php",  
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        cache: false, 
        success: function(data) {
            #Здесь нужен обработчик каждой строки json отдельно.
        }                       
    });
}
```

В php у меня цикл

```
$sql=$mysqli->query("select * from `inventory` where `active='0'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql)) {
    $arr = array('id' => $row['id'],'type' => $row['type'],'name' => $row['name']);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

В ответе получаю это

```
{"id":"185","type":"client","name":"valera"}
{"id":"186","type":"boss","name":"andrey"}
{"id":"187","type":"client","name":"ivan"}
```

Как обработать в этой js функции этот массив отдельно каждую строку?

Comment: Для начала сделайте массив `$arr = []; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql)) {
    $arr[] = array('id' => $row['id'],'type' => $row['type'],'name' => $row['name']); }
    echo json_encode($arr);` И в js используйте любой метод для перебора массива

Comment: @splash58 Могли бы вы пример обработчика указать?

Comment: я написал ответ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сначала сделайте общий массив в php

```
$arr = []; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
   $arr[] = array('id' => $row['id'],'type' => $row['type'],'name' => $row['name']); 
} 
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Затем в js используйте любой метод для перебора массива, например

```js
data = [
{"id":"185","type":"client","name":"valera"},
{"id":"186","type":"boss","name":"andrey"},
{"id":"187","type":"client","name":"ivan"}
];

data.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: используя ваш код у меня теперь выводится только последняя строка.

Comment: отожмите галку приема ответа и сделайте print_r($arr). Что там?

Comment: там массив из одной последней строки.. Как сделать чтобы в цикле все строки в один массив складывались?

Comment: у вас написано вот так ` $arr[] = ` ?

Answer (score 0):

> В php у меня цикл

Магия

```
$sql=$mysqli->query("select id,type,name from `inventory` where `active='0'");
echo json_encode($sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```